# How to get JSON object data from a webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to web and I need to get JSON object for a webpage that has data displayed this:

```
{
"expires": "2011-09-24T01:00:00",
"currencies": {
    "BZD": {
        "a": "2.02200",
        "b": "1.94826"
    },
    "YER": {
        "a": "220.050",
        "b": "212.950"
    }
}
```

I tried use jquery's $.getJSON to get the object but it didn't work.

`<script>
    $.getJSON("http://m.somewebsite.com/data", 
     {
    format: "json"
    },
      function(data) {
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = data;
      });
    </script>`

I am wondering how to get this information correctly?

Comment: [There is no such thing as a JSON object.](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) Also, if you use `document.write()` there, you will replace the current contents of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for this to work, you need to define jsonp, jsonp allows you to gain read access to another site's document, as the alternate version is barred.

```
$.getJSON("http://m.somewebsite.com/data?callback=?", { format: "json" }, function(data) { document.write(data); });
```

Comment: I am unsure if $.getJSON is the correct command that I want to use.
Because the function would work for the flicker api: "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?"

but not the link I had, even with the 'jsonp' at the end

Comment: To get a `jsonp` response using `$.getJSON`, you don't add a fourth argument. You need to add `callback=?` to the url. `jsonp` doesn't make an XHR request, but rather makes a script request that is not subject to the Same Origin Policy of XHR requests. The returned script is a function call, that passes the JavaScript object you're looking for as an argument. So if the server isn't set up to send a proper response for `jsonp`, it won't work.

Comment: Hmm, I see.
Is there any alternative way of getting information from the website then?